# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sandbox, cuckoo

I am trying to run cuckoo api. Cuckoo web is working fine on my system. But when I tried cuckoo api, I got the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1512, in handle_user_exception
  return self.handle_http_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1471, in handle_http_exception
  return handler(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/apps/api.py", line 719, in api_auth_required
  401, "Authentication in the form of an "
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/apps/api.py", line 36, in json_error
  r = jsonify(message=message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 251, in jsonify
  if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
  return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)

AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'

2020-04-02 18:50:39,640 [werkzeug] INFO: 192.168.100.94 - - [02/Apr/2020 18:50:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried to change api.py by adding the following code:

```
@app.route("/publish/epoch/end/", methods=['POST'])
def publish():
    #payload = request.form.get('data')
    payload = unquote(request.data.split('=')[1]).replace('+','')
    try:
       `enter code here` data = json.loads(payload)
    except:
        return {'error':'invalid payload'}

    def notify():
        msg = str(time.time())
        for sub in subscriptions[:]:
            sub.put(payload)

    gevent.spawn(notify)
    return "OK"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        model.save()
        # Failure to return a redirect or render_template
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

But that didn't help me. What could be the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 19):

Per this [github issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2549), another option is to disable JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR in your config file.

```
class Config:
  # Other configs
  JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR = False
```

or

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = False
```

Answer (score 11):

The `request.is_xhr` property was deprecated since Werkzeug 0.13 and removed in Werkzeug 1.0.0. You will get this error when using Flask <= 0.12.4 and Werkzeug >=1.0.0 because Flask uses this property in the source before the 1.0.0 version. You can just upgrade Flask (>=1.0.0) to fix this issue:

```
$ pip install -U flask
```

Otherwise, you can also downgrade Werkzeug to 0.16.1:

```
$ pip install werkzeug==0.16.1
```

Answer (score 9):

The `request.is_xhr` method has been deprecated & removed, as it was unreliable. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871003/identify-if-flask-request-is-from-javascript-or-not) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131900/weird-is-xhr-error-when-deploying-flask-app-to-heroku) about why it was removed.

You may need to pin your local version of Werkzeug to something that is compatible with Cuckoo's pinned version of Flask ([example here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/3488/commits/cbb680083cd11bd8623712051294278b68fed6e4)) until Cuckoo updates to a newer version of Flask.

Comment: Thanku alot Mr Simmer. But I am totally new to python. I dont know how to do what u said

Comment: If you have an `install_requires = [...]` section in the `setup.py` file in your app, add this line inside the brackets :

`"Werkzeug==0.16"`