# Error in postman 500 internal server error while getting get request results

Tags: flask, anaconda, postman, spyder

I'm building blockchain using flask (1.1.1) and spyder (version =4.1.4).I run the whole code and go to postman to get the result of GET request (get_chain) and it works .But when I run http://127.0.0.1:/5000/mine_block.It is showing 500 internal server error. Here is full code screenshot
[Full code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygtf4.png)
 [mine block Get requestresults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbnEh.png)

---

- 

Comment: Usually the "500 internal server error" means that there is a python error in the flask application, do you see an error in your flask app when you send the GET request ? if so, please copy the error and add it to your question.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The problem's solution has been given in this link : [AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60992849/attributeerror-request-object-has-no-attribute-is-xhr)

Or you can simply disable JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR in your config file.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = False
```