# I am not able to run blockchain.py

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask.
I am testing a blockchain that I found on github and I am facing this error:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-10-04 21:37:54,221] ERROR in app: Exception on /mine_block [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\T357\Desktop\blockchain.py", line 84, in mine_block
    return jsonify(response), 200
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\json.py", line 251, in jsonify
    if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
  File "C:\Users\T357\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2020 21:37:54] "←[35m←[1mGET /mine_block HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
```

As you can see the error is AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'

So could anyone lead me in the right direction? I cannot find a solution on my own.
Thanks

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65684861/5511849).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed see below link, try using newer version of flask.though there is a quick fix as well, just set

```
JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR = False
```

There is no json.py in recent versions of flask in `python3.8/site-packages/flask`.
But if there is one in your flask version you will see, this line

```
if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
```

Here the `request.is_xhr` is deprecated.So you need to set JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR to False.

See this issue https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2549 for more details.